# Volume and surface area of elliptic torus

Tags: integration

ok, so i have an elliptic torus, parametrised as (i'll just copy the mathematica syntax):
rr := {(R + a Cos[v]) Cos[u], (R + a Cos[v]) Sin[u], b Sin[v]}
R is here the 'big' radius, and a and b are the semi-axises of the ellipse.

To calculate the surface are we first calculate the derivatives:
ru:=D[rr, u] 
rv:=D[rr, v] 
dA:=Norm[Cross[ru, rv]]
and A=Integrate[dA, {u, 0, 2 Pi},  {v, 0, 2 Pi}]

is this correct? I am asking, because the wolfram page gives me a different solution (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticTorus.html) 
furthermore i need to calculate also the volume of this torus, but first i'd like to know if the surface area is correct?

ok, so assuming that the above is correct - how do i then calculate the volume of such body? I know that i need to calculate the Jacobian determinant and then integrate over the two angles and on of the length parameters, but i can't seem to get it together correctly...
If this would be a normal torus (with circular cross section) the length integration would be simply over $\text{d}r$ from $0$ to $r$ (the circle radius). With the case of the ellipse, it is not so clear anymore...

tnx,
u

Comment: See [math notation guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) for proper formatting of formulas.

Comment: actually I wanted to leave it in the Mathematica syntax, because there might be an error in how i use the mathematica formulas...

Comment: In that case, your question is about using Mathematica, hence is off-topic here. See [Mathematica.SE]

Comment: tnx, i'll check. I also extended my question, so if you have any ideas how to properly calculate this, i'd be very grateful

Comment: The cross-section of the torus is an ellipse with area $\pi a b$, so your volume is simply $(2 \pi R) (\pi a b)$ = $2 \pi^2 R a b$?

Comment: yeah, i could also use the Pappus's theorem, but i would like to get tHrough rigorously with Jacobian - i need to know how to do it using this approach